# The [player] is dead and can't respawn

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

A [question was asked today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166434/how-to-use-trackbar-in-mp3-player-to-change-song-time-in-c) that contained multiple errors that needed to be fixed via an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6859508).

I went forth with the editing, but noticed that the question was tagged with [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player), looking into the tag there's a *clear* need for it to be removed:

- It's ambiguous- What type of player? Audio player? Video player? In addition to this there exist already the tags [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player) and [video-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-player)
- Does not refer to a specific library
- It is not possible to be an expert in [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) as it's **too broad**

I don't think this tag's useful and should be removed.

Some of the tag's stats:

- 1149 questions
- Almost 20% of all tagged questions have gone unanswered (220 unanswered questions, 1149 tagged questions total)
- The question with the highest score in [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) is 18, and the answer in [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) with the highest score is at 58 (60/2) with a 100-rep bounty.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +73/-5 A1 (Saying Yes): +35/0.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this tag should be burninated.  Ready [player] Trogdor.

Comment: Bit funny, but audio-player/video-player wasn't the first thing that came to my mind while I read just the title. It was infact gaming (player)!

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +167/-5. A1 (Saying Yes): +128/0. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: @rgettman I was about to use that one :)

Comment: Mine was a seduction artist, as they are called "players" when they enter the "game" in a club LOL @Viney But second thing I thought was that one yeah

Comment: @BhargavRao As of a few minutes ago, 100% of remaining questions in the tag are closed. Should we wait for the Roomba tonight, and then figure out what to do with the remaining closed ones?

Comment: Thanks for the update @EJoshuaS. I'll spend some time at night, and this weekend, go through all the remaining questions and get this done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use the [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player) tag for [questions related to audio or music players.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music+player+or+audio+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50), which are tagged with either [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) or  [mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mp3)
- Use the [video-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-player) tag for [questions related to video players,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movie+player+or+video+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50) that are also tagged with [video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video) or [movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movie).
- [For the questions about HTML players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+player+or+html5+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50), that are tagged [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), use either  [html5-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-video) or [html5-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-audio) as appropriate.
- [For the questions about media players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50) use [media-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-player).
- [For the questions related to the Android MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media+player+android) use  [android-mediaplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediaplayer), instead.
- [For the questions about Stage-Player](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplayer%5D+-%5Bvideo%5D+-%5Baudio%5D+-%5Bmp3%5D+-%5Bhtml%5D+-%5Bhtml5%5D+-%5Bmusic%5D+-%5Bmovie%5D+-%5Bmedia%5D+stage), use [player-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player-stage) instead.
- For the questions related to players in game development, use [game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development) instead.
- Use the [mpmovieplayercontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpmovieplayercontroller) tag for the now deprecated MPMoviePlayerController related questions (iOS development).
- [For the questions related to flash players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash+player), use [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) instead.

## Progress:

The [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=player),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplayer%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplayer%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplayer%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplayer%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191114)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=284647)

[image: burnination progress chart]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Large Tag Guidance

Remember that [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) has more than 1100 questions. Therefore do not go through all of them! Retag the ones which are worth saving (usually the top voted posts) and vote to close the unsalvageable questions (usually the very low scored).

#### [Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307009)

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: @double-beep  What's different between how you're generating the progress chart embedded here and the one on rodgort?  Yours has retags staying well ahead of closes since the 8th vs the other having the latter catch up repeatedly as well as significantly fewer questions remaining.

Comment: Hey @DanNeely! Join us in the [burnination chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191114)! You will find some explanations.

Answer (score 130):

Lets split it up and burn it. **It's too broad**, and while it might (arguably) be *a contextual tag*, **there are better tags for adding context** than just [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player).

[player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) looks like it can be split into a few different tags, at least [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player) and [video-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-player) to start.

- There are [141 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music+player+or+audio+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50) tagged [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) or [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player), which sounds *a lot* like [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player). There are also [62 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player+mp3?sort=newest&pageSize=50) tagged [mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mp3) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) which might also fit into the category. These should be easy to re-tag.
- There are [224 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movie+player+or+video+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50) tagged [video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) or [movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movie) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player), which also happens to sound like [video-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-player). These should also be easy to re-tag.
- There are [127 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+player+or+html5+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50) tagged [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) or [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) which look like they would fit under [html5-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-video). This is the tag for the HTML5 `<video>` element that many of these questions refer to. If it is for the `<audio>` element, then use [html5-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-audio).
- There are [148 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media+player?sort=newest&pageSize=50) tagged [media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) which sounds like [media-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-player). These should only be re-tagged as [media-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-player) if they do not fit into any of the recommended re-tags. [67 of those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media+player+android) look like they can be re-tagged as [android-mediaplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediaplayer).

That leaves us with [549 other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player+-video+-audio+-mp3+-html+-html5+-music+-movie+-media?sort=newest&pageSize=50) which cover a variety of subjects, such as [player-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player-stage).

While some of them are for file extensions, like [avi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avi+player)/[mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mp4+player)/[wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wav+player)/[flv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flv+player)/[swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swf+player), and should be re-tagged appropriately, there do appear to be [a decent number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash+player) of [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) questions. Some of these will fall under the re-tags above, but quite a few of them are off-topic and should be looked at more closely. Those which aren't off-topic can most likely stand alone with just [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash).

Comment: Wow, when I clicked on this thread I thought [player] was about... the player. The guy in front of the screen playing a computer game. So yes, it's ambiguous and not helpful. Please cleanse it with fire and re-tag it with something useful.

Comment: there are a bunch of robotics related ones which belong in [player-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/player-stage) - adding [robot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplayer%5D+-%5Bvideo%5D+-%5Baudio%5D+-%5Bmp3%5D+-%5Bhtml%5D+-%5Bhtml5%5D+-%5Bmusic%5D+-%5Bmovie%5D+-%5Bmedia%5D+robot) or [stage](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplayer%5D+-%5Bvideo%5D+-%5Baudio%5D+-%5Bmp3%5D+-%5Bhtml%5D+-%5Bhtml5%5D+-%5Bmusic%5D+-%5Bmovie%5D+-%5Bmedia%5D+stage) to the "433 other questions" search finds many of these.

Comment: @Stobor please edit those along with the searches you used to find them into the list.

Comment: if we're going to use [player-stage] as a merge target like @Stobor suggests, someone needs to write a wiki for it.

Comment: @DanNeely I've made a first pass at a tag wiki (it has been over 10 years since I used Player/Stage). I'll come back to clean it up later.

Comment: @nvoigt Literally i was thinking the same thing... The question itself attracted me because of the tag, it is too BROAD. I don't really come to meta otherwise but this question made me click on it two days a row.