# Let's give [videoplayer] the hyphen it has always wanted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

It seems we largely agree that [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) [should be set on fire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284647/359284). In my [recommended list of re-tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284741/359284), the tags [audo-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audo-player), [media-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-player), and [videoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoplayer) came up as possible landing places.

Unfortunately [videoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoplayer) looks a bit out of place within the group, missing the hyphen it never got. We can't create [video-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-player), because it is too similar to [videoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoplayer), so it's currently impossible for us to make it a synonym and fix this issue.

[image: The tag error notice]

**Which leaves us with the important questions:**

- Should [videoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoplayer) be given a hyphen?
- Who has the power to create [video-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-player)?

Comment: looks like you got your wish ! nice !