# Rename tag: [webcryptoapi] to [web-crypto-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Just a small improvement: I think [webcryptoapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcryptoapi) should be renamed since:

- It's better readable with dashes.
- The suggested naming policy is to

> combine multiple words into single-words with dashes

Comment: There are only 3 questions, so if you get no objections it would be really easy to do.  Be sure to update the wiki for the new name as well.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: renaming would preserve the [tag history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24567951/revisions), though

Comment: @Bergi Not much history there that NEEDs to be preserved.  It is a small tag, no need to involve a moderator.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I'm fairly certain only mods can do naming changes that are [limited to just the hyphenation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284785/lets-give-videoplayer-the-hyphen-it-has-always-wanted). Unless you wanted to let the tag die, and then bring it back the next day with the right name.

Comment: @KevinBrown Ah yes, you are right there.

Answer (score 33):

I googled "web crypto" and found the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) for it. It seems like the convention there and in other places where it is discussed is to call it "WebCrypto" or "webcrypto". Renaming the tag to [webcrypto-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcrypto-api) feels more natural to me. Just [webcrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcrypto) without `-api` would be even better.

Comment: webcrypto-api sounds like a good choice :-)