# What can we do with [audio-playing] and [audio-player] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

So, we got the tag [Audio-playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-playing), which has 48 questions on it.

The description follows:

Questions related to the playback of sampled audio data. For questions specific to sounds, use [audio].

But there is an [dedicated audio-player tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player)
The description:

An software specialized in playing audio of different formats and/or manage audio libraries.

Can't we fuse these two together? An audio-player question is "related to the playback of sampled audio data." This makes, in my opinion, the Audio-playing tag useles.

For what the audio-player can't handle, the tag audio already can.

Why don't we [Kill along with [player]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284647/kill-the-player) the [audio-playing] tag?

Comment: @animuson♦  Why did you tagged this with "status-completed"? I didn't getted it.

Comment: You asked for [tag:audio-playing] and [tag:audio-player] to be merged, which has been done. Is there something else you wanted?

Comment: @animuson oh, yes. That's what I wanted, it's just that it was too fast; my browser still had the cached version. Sorry about that.